# Read Excel data and use it in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This script is to read data from excel and use it in selenium script. This uses Apache POI to read the data, store it in variables and use it.

Comment: whats the question ?

Comment: @MatheswaranKanagarajan Can you consider updating the Question area with your work, research, relevant HTML DOM & error stack trace for further analysis by SO volunteers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code. I have taken facebook as sample application.

```
 package testPackage;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 import org.testng.annotations.*;
 import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

 import jxl.Sheet;
 import jxl.Workbook;
 import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

 public class ExcelReadingwithDP {

 WebDriver driver;
 @BeforeTest
 public void OpenApp()
 {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "E:/Selenium/Webdriver/Softwares/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://facebook.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }


 @Test(dataProvider="empLogin")
 public void login(String username, String password)
 {
     WebElement login1 = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
     login1.clear();
    login1.sendKeys(username);
    WebElement passwd=driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    passwd.clear();
    passwd.sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u_0_q']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement back = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='blueBarDOMInspector']/div/div[1]/div/div/h1/a/i"));
    back.click();
 }


 @DataProvider(name="empLogin")
  public Object[][] logindata()
 {
     Object[][] arrayobject = getexceldata("E://Deepak/IntranetLogin.xls","Sheet1");
     return arrayobject;
 }

public String[][] getexceldata(String filename, String sheetname)
{

    String[][] arrayexceldata = null;
    try
    {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetname);
    int row = sh.getRows();
    int col = sh.getColumns();
    arrayexceldata = new String[row-1][col];
    for (int i=1;i< row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            arrayexceldata[i-1][j]=sh.getCell(j,i).getContents();
        }
    }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayexceldata;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * Download Apache POI from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.16-20170419.zip
 * 
 */

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FormFill {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\data.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
            String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((short) 1);
            String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();

            System.out.println("A1: " + a1Val);
            System.out.println("B1: " + b1Val);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String url = "http://thedemosite.co.uk/addauser.php";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        //Thread.sleep(30000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(a1Val);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(b1Val);


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel csv is better than Excel because Excel more time to read the data but csv is fast.

private static final String CSV_SEPARATOR = ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";

```
public List<String[]> parseFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        br.readLine(); // skip header;
        String line = br.readLine();
        List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList();
        while (line != null) {
            //System.out.println(line.toString());
            lines.add(line.split(CSV_SEPARATOR));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return lines;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```